# Rails - Trying to reconstruct and save a date before validation -> invalid date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, methods

I wrote a simple method which save a date in a db field (mydate:date) but it returns an "invalid date" error message.

note: I use simple_form

## User.rb

```
attr_accessor:user_birthday_1i, :user_birthday_2i, :user_birthday_3i

before_validation :prepare_mydate

def prepare_mydate
  self.mydate = Date.new(self.user_birthday_1i.to_i, self.user_birthday_2i.to_i, self.user_birthday_3i.to_i)
end
```

## form

```
<%= f.input :birthday, :as => :date, 
                       :start_year => Date.today.year - 100,
                       :end_year => Date.today.year,
                       :order => [:month, :day, :year],
                       :prompt => true %>
```

What's wrong with this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
before_save :prepare_mydate

def prepare_mydate
  self.mydate = Date.new(self.birthday.year.to_i, self.birthday.month.to_i, birthday_day.to_i)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>It looks like your form order is :month, :day, :year, whereas `Date.new` order is year, month, day.</strike>

I suggest you use the [`date_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) helper.

Comment: Thanks I ve tried to order it, but it doesn't change anything :(